# wordpress querystring not reading after rewritten

Tags: wordpress, url

Using wordpress on IIS 7 in Windows Server 2008.  In a header.php file I have an hardcoded link

```
<a href="www.gohere.com?querystring=value">Link</a>
```

Which after the page loads the link automatically renders to

```
<a href="www.gohere.com/?querystring=value">Link</a>
```

The slash is also added in the address bar for the URL if I put only "www.gohere.com?querystring=value".  Which would be ok but in my php code I cannot read the value of the querystring.

Code to read the qs

```
$getThis = get_query_var('querystring');   
if(!empty($getThis)){
    ...DO WORK BUT DOESN'T GET HERE
}
```

And the rewrite section of web.config as this does some reading/writing.  No htaccess as I am on IIS

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="wp-includes/ms-files.php?file={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 7" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I was using the wrong php code to get value of querystring.  Looks like this works fine.

```
$getThis  = $_GET['querystring'];
```